# Relation between set of sets and subset of subsetless sets]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am attempting to describe a relationship between a set of sets S and a subset of S, T, as follows:

$$T = \{ x | x ∈ S \land \forall y(y \in S ⇒ y \not\subset x) \}$$

As I understand, this means T is a subset of S containing all sets of which no other members of S are strict subsets.

Is there a mathematical term that describes this relationship?

Comment: Inclusion minimal, or just $\subseteq$-minimal.

Comment: See [Maximal and minimal elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements). These terms are not only defined for the *inclusion* relation $\subseteq$, but for any [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (or even preorder). $T$ is probably just the "set of all minimal subsets in $S$".